# LaTex Text Justify in two columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm new to Latex environment, and I'm dealing with text alignment. Probably this question was already asked, but I didn't manage to find the answer elsewhere.
I want to put the text next to the red vertical line. I added that vertical line with "Paint", it's not part of the document.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way should be this: load package `enumerate`  and use an `enumerate` environment along these lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, widest=$\textcolor{DarkSeaGreen}{\ding{224}}\qquad Δ> 0$, font=\color{DarkSeaGreen}]

   \item[\ding{224}\quad$\Delta>0$] È facile rendersi conto che che se sotto abbiamo radice un numero positive, grazie al simbolo $\pm$, abbiamo \textbf{due soluzioni distinte}:
    \[ x = \frac{-b + √{Δ}}{2a}\quad e\quad x = \frac{-b - √{Δ}}{2a} \]%

   \item[\ding{224}\quad$\Delta=0$] La formula diventa …

   \item[\ding{224}\quad$\Delta<0$] La formula presenta …

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]